# Speeding up an algorithm for finding the number of distinct lines

Tags: python

Is there a way to speed up the following python code:

```
auxdict = {0:0}
divdict = {}

def divisors(n):
    divisors = []
    for i in range(1, int(n**0.5) + 1):
        if (n % i == 0):
            divisors.extend([i, n/i])
    divisors = list(set(divisors))
    divisors.sort()
    return divisors

def aux(k):
    if k in auxdict:
        return auxdict[k]
    else:
        if not k in divdict:
            divdict[k] = divisors(k)
        r = sum(map(aux, divdict[k][:len(divdict[k])-1]))
        auxdict[k] = (k+1)**3 - k**3 - r
        return auxdict[k]

def lines(k):
    result = 0
    for i in range(int(k/2),0,-1):
        result += int(k/i-1) * aux(i)
    return (k+1)**3 - result - 1

for i in [10**6, 10**10]:
    print i, lines(i)
```

It is a modified version of a Mathematica code I found. The code finds the maximum number of distinct lines in a 3D cube of lattices of size n: http://oeis.org/A090025

The problem is the code is very slow and doesn't work for larger values. I want to evaluate lines(10**10)

Comment: Um, that first for loop will go over `10 ** 10 / 2` values; even if you could get each call to `aux` down to a millisecond that'd take two months. You'll need a different algorithm.

Comment: What OS is this to be run on?

Comment: @Vijay I'm running Mac OS X 10.6 .. Does the OS type matter?

Comment: You probably want to use `xrange` instead of `range` so you don't have a list of 5 billion integers. Not that it will help *all* that much.

Comment: In Linux you could so something like:  
sort myfile.txt | uniq -uc <- call that using "subprocess.Popen", I assume in OSX there is a similar function... Assuming they are actually stored in "lines" in a file ;)

Comment: How/where is this data stored before you have it in PY?

Comment: there are better algorithm on the oeis page you linked

Comment: @Wooble I used xrange .. still very slow

Comment: @Vijay I'm not storing any data. As Dougal mentioned, the algorithm itself is slow.

Comment: @Simon Which one?

Comment: @OsamaGamal I thought that perhaps you were reading the data in from a file, if you were then I would have another idea on how you could speed it up, where would the data originate from when this method is executed in the real world?

Comment: @Vijay Check this: http://projecteuler.net/problem=388

Comment: `a(n) = Sum(moebius(k)*((floor(n/k)+1)^3-1), k=1..n)` Don't know if it is correct though

Comment: @OsamaGamal I'll whip something up... Or I'll find my PE login and grab my old solution :)

Comment: Don't you get overflow error with 10**10? I do...

Comment: My laptop hangs and start asking for force closing apps after a while :)

Comment: @Wooble EDIT: You are right.  I was thinking he could use a parallel algorithm, and I would have swore Amazon offer distributed computing.

Comment: use `sqrt(n)` instead of `n**0.5`. It's a bit faster

Comment: Also, if you are using python 2.x, integer division is the default. There is no need to type cast k/2 as `int()`

Comment: @JoelCornett It's far better to do `k // 2` than using `k / 2` as integer division.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can improve your divisors function:

**Version 1:** (not includes n)

```
def divisors(n):
    """Return the divisors of n (including 1)"""
    if(n == 1):
        return (0)

    divs = set([1])
    r = floor(sqrt(n))
    if(r**2 == n):
        divs.add(r)

    f = 2
    step = 1
    if(n & 1 == 1):
        f = 3
        step = 2

    while(f <= r):
        if(n % f == 0):
            divs.add(n/f)
            divs.add(f)
        f = f + step

    return sorted(divs)
```

**Version 2:** (includes n) from [here](http://numericalrecipes.wordpress.com/2009/05/13/divisors/)

```
def divisors2(n) :
    """
    Generates all divisors, unordered, from the prime factorization.
    """
    factors = factorI(n)
    ps = sorted(set(factors))
    omega = len(ps)

    def rec_gen(n = 0) :
        if n == omega :
            yield 1
        else :
            pows = [1]
            for j in xrange(factors.count(ps[n])) :
                pows += [pows[-1] * ps[n]]
            for q in rec_gen(n + 1) :
                for p in pows :
                    yield p * q

    for p in rec_gen() :
        yield p
```

where `factorI` is:

```
def factorI(n):
    """Returns the factors of n."""
    lst = []
    num = int(n)
    if(num & 1 == 0):
        lst.append(2)
        num /= 2
        while(num & 1 == 0):
            lst.append(2)
            num /= 2

    factor = 3
    maxFactor = sqrt(num)
    while num>1 and factor <= maxFactor:
        if(num % factor == 0):
            num /= factor
            lst.append(factor)
            while(num % factor == 0):
                lst.append(factor)
                num /= factor
            maxFactor = sqrt(num)
        factor += 2

    if(num > 1):
        lst.append(num)
    return lst
```

For efficiency reasons you could also make generator functions.

Comment: I tried it .. It's 20seconds slower than mine for solving N=10**6 .. I'm not sure why

Comment: @OsamaGamal: There's an extra `pow()` operation at the beginning of this one. Also, the while loop is slower than iterating over the elements of `range()` or `xrange()`.

Comment: Thats kind of weird. The first pow operations is just for checking for perfect squares. But the while loop must be faster, due to the heavily reduced interations. I will have a look at it if i found some time

Comment: Ok. Found another algorithm based on factorization. Will updating the post...

Comment: That's better. Now it is running a little bit faster for 10**6. I just had to update the line number 5 in the aux(k) function to: divdict[k] = sorted(list(divisors(k)))